# Why does the bitmap from the cache in the folllowing code return null?

Tags: android, android-lru-cache

The following code should be caching image into the memory but every time I run it the cache always return null. What could be the issue? I have used the code as exactly as it is on the Android Developer website.

```
private lateinit var memoryCache: LruCache<String, Bitmap>

fun load(imageUrl: String, imageView: ImageView) {

    val maxMemory = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt()

    val cacheSize = maxMemory / 8

    memoryCache = object : LruCache<String, Bitmap>(cacheSize) {

        override fun sizeOf(key: String, bitmap: Bitmap): Int {

            return bitmap.byteCount / 1024

        }
    }

    CoroutineScope(IO).launch {

        loadBitmap(imageUrl, imageView)

    }

}

suspend fun loadBitmap(imageUrl: String, imageView: ImageView) {

    val bitmap: Bitmap? = memoryCache[imageUrl]

    if (bitmap != null) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        }
    } else {
        val url = URL(imageUrl)
        val image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream())

        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(image)
        }
        memoryCache.put(imageUrl, image)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your memoryCache is empty.

Comment: @blackapps https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap#kotlin this

Comment: `memoryCache.put(imageUrl, image)` Isnt there a return value?

Comment: @blackapps apparently no. I even added .also to display the value after putting it in the cache and it displayed nothing

Comment: Quote: `Note: In this example, one eighth of the application memory is allocated for our cache. On a normal/hdpi device this is a minimum of around 4MB (32/8). A full screen GridView filled with images on a device with 800x480 resolution would use around 1.5MB (800*480*4 bytes), so this would cache a minimum of around 2.5 pages of images in memory.` Check the size of your bitmap.

Comment: @blackapps Thanks so how much should I allocate the memory?

Comment: Please first tell if that was the problem. And if it was then allocate more. But... memory caches for bitmaps are a bad idea as it takes so much memory. If you need a memory cache then save .jpgs in it instead of bitmaps. But you could use a file cache too.

Comment: @blackapps the size is 96000000 that large

Comment: Is that the size of the cache or the bitmap? You should tell both of course. Only then we can see if the bitmap would fit in the cache.

Comment: Also determine how many elements are in your cache right after putting one in.

Comment: @blackapps that's the size of one bitmap to be cached. I am afraid Idk how to determine the size of the cache.

Comment: ????? `val cacheSize = maxMemory / 8`.

Comment: @blackapps max size is 524288 wow thats so small.

Comment: `max size` ? was that cacheSize or maxMemory? (Please be exact).

Comment: @blackapps  after removing the divide by 1024 the size is 536870912 and still it doesnt show

Comment: Quote: `// Get max available VM memory, exceeding this amount will throw an
    // OutOfMemory exception.` , You have that exception?

Comment: @blackapps max memory 524288 Cache size  65536

Comment: @blackapps I have no exception its just doesn't show even with max memory allocated

Comment: 524.288 KB you mean. Please remember the `/1024`.

Comment: Sorry i see now that that exception will come at creating the cache. Not at putting something in it. But then... no warning if the cache is full or to small at put() is no good.

Comment: Cache size is 65 MB and your bitmap was an unreadable  96000000 or better 96.000.000 hence 96 MB. Does not fit indeed. You can easily enlarge the cache size to hold that bitmap.

Comment: @blackapps thanks. I have tried that it doesnt work though